# default aspx not showing in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web

When i am making a empty asp project in VS 2012, The default .aspx is not showing in Showing Explorer,Where can i get or make default.aspx[image]

Comment: Please do some search on web, you can find easy solution, if not then after post question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click Project -> Add -> New Item...

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Website-> Add New Item-> Web form-> Add**